# Hadoop job returns exception "classNotFound"

Tags: java, hadoop

I am trying to launch a word count map reduce on hadoop. When I ask hadoop to do the job, it returns the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sdz.hadoop.wordcount.WordCountDriver
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:232)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:153)
```

This is the output of:

```
 hadoop jar wordcount.jar sdz.hadoop.wordcount.WordCountDriver ../source.txt ../results
```

---

The jar file looks like this:

```
$jar tf wordcount.jar 
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
WordCountReducer.class
WordCountMapper.class
WordCountDriver.class
```

---

The jar file has been generated with the following command/output:

```
$jar -cvf wordcount.jar .
added manifest
adding: WordCountReducer.class(in = 1720) (out= 723)(deflated 57%)
adding: WordCountMapper.class(in = 2347) (out= 936)(deflated 60%)
adding: WordCountDriver.class(in = 2278) (out= 1118)(deflated 50%)
```

---

The classes have been generated from the following command:

```
javac -classpath $HADOOP_CLASSPATH WordCount*.java
```

---

The java files contain (I know for the useless imports):

- [WordCountReducer.java](https://gist.github.com/floriancastelain/1f670288e69466c08f6743503564d771)
- [WordCountMapper.java](https://gist.github.com/floriancastelain/5fbe544690639a495da8f4db670b019a)
- [WordCountDriver.java](https://gist.github.com/floriancastelain/fe4993046f8971ce87fb20e3fd85d530)

---

Other questions on this said to add the "job.setJarByClass(WordCountDriver.class);". But I already have it. So what is my mistake?

Comment: Which tutorial did you follow?

Comment: @cricket_007 https://openclassrooms.com/fr/courses/4297166-realisez-des-calculs-distribues-sur-des-donnees-massives/ (french) I do not recommend it 'cause the way they organize it (like they put prereq AFTER task) is bad and they do not give a lot of tech info (for example on the installation of hadoop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The job will fail as it tries (and fails) to find your classes within the jar at the location:

```
sdz/hadoop/wordcount/WordCountDriver.class
```

The quickest solution is to simply remove the package name from your run command (and any package declarations within your classes themselves):

```
hadoop jar wordcount.jar WordCountDriver ../source.txt ../results
```

A more stable solution would be to have your jar properly built by a build tool like Maven or Gradle.

Comment: That was it, thanks. 
For the build technique, I was following a tutorial. But won't do the same mistake again.

Comment: No problem, glad I was able to help.